# Is it possible to load a script from a string without using loadstring

Tags: lua

The title says it all, basically i want to load my script from a string without using loadstring so if someone could link me a pure loadstring function that would be cool, like the lua code for loadstring

Sorry for bad english, English is my second language

Comment: SO isn't really for recommending libraries. Besides, did you Google for it? E.g. `custom lua loadstring` gives plenty of results, with some actually very helpful.

Comment: Here you go, [implementation for loadstring](https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/lauxlib.c.html#luaL_loadstring)

Comment: In other words, you want to implement your own `loadstring` in pure Lua?  It looks like you need a Lua interpreter written in Lua.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please say why you don't want to use `loadstring`, because this function is literally designed for this kind of job.

If it's a challenge you have and you **don't care about it being fast** you can technically:

1. Save the string to a file
2. Run that file using `dofile`

I hope that answers your question well!
In case you have any further questions, do let me know!

Also, here's a page from Lua docs that is related and you might want to read it!
https://www.lua.org/pil/8.html